# Create AWS access key that only allow s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to create an AWS access key that only allow s3. That means the key can't be used with any other service. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is it possible** ??

Yes. You can use [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/)

Ideally you should never give your admin/main account credentials for anything other than creating different IAM.

So create different users with needed securities, and create access keys for them and use it.

**HOW** ??

You can directly create from [AWS Console IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#iam)

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

or if you S3Browser please follow [this](http://s3browser.com/aws-iam-create-delete-access-keys.php)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, create an IAM user in the aws console and then assign it a policy like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1397557252000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```